# Visualizing inequality in arbitrary dimension

Tags: inequality, inner-products

In my studies of analysis I was recently stumped by this:

> We have a given vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and I am looking at the inequalities
>   $ 0 < y^T x < 1 $ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

I know the inequality $ 0 < y^T x $ means a halfspace separated by a hyperplane
$ y^T x = 0 $ but can we visualize $ 0 < y^T x < 1 $? Perhaps there is intuition in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ visualizing the satisfying region? I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminded me of an old joke

> An engineer, a physicist, and a mathematician are discussing how to visualize four dimensions:
>
> Engineer: I never really get it
>
> Phyicist: Oh it's really easy, just imagine three dimensional space over a time- that adds your fourth dimension.
>
> Mathematician: No, it's way easier than that; just imagine $\mathbb{R}^n$ then set n equal to 4.

Perhaps a better visualization is that of a linear function

$$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ny_i\cdot x_i$$

Thus the equality
$$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=c$$
defines its level sets.

This are the [sublevel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets)

$$L_{c^-}=\{(x_1,...,x_n)|f(x_1,...,x_n)\le c\}$$
and the [superlevel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets)
$$L_{c^+}=\{(x_1,...,x_n)|f(x_1,...,x_n)\ge c\}$$

Now imagine the intersection of the sets

$$M=L_{0^+}\cap L_{1^-}$$
This is the set of points you are thinking of.